# TestFlight does not showing crash log for specific Beta Tester

Tags: testflight, crash-reports, firebase-crash-reporting, testflight-public-link

We have recently released an app on TestFlight, and TestFlight includes a useful feature for automatically capturing crash reports. Whenever a user encounters a crash, TestFlight usually displays a dialogue prompting them to share the crash details with the developer or Apple portal. However, one of our users reported that they did not receive this dialogue, despite having the "Share iPhone & Watch Analytics" option enabled. As a result, we are unable to access the crash logs for further investigation. It seems that no other users are currently experiencing the crash, or they may not be encountering the specific circumstances that prevent the crash dialogue from appearing. Moreover he tried to find that crash log .ips file in "Analytics Data" but its not visible.

Even its not reported on crashlytics.

\Feature : Fetching contacts from contact book through CNContacts and crashed when google sync for contacts is enable.

- External testing group - not uploaded though ad-hoc profile - beta-reports is active

Tried : Downloaded the app from testflight and intentionally crashed the app and it was reported on "Crashes" tab on App Store Connect.

Seeking for your prompt assistance any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I learned that when an operating system is unable to allocate enough memory to load a specific task, it chooses to terminate the application rather than considering it a crash. As a result of this intentional termination by the operating system, the "Share Crash" dialogue does not appear. This behavior is designed to prevent system instability and ensure the overall smooth functioning of the operating system. Instead of allowing the application to continue running with limited resources and potentially causing further issues, the operating system terminates it to free up memory and prioritize the stability of the system. Consequently, since the termination is a deliberate action by the operating system, it is categorized as an OS termination rather than a crash, which explains why the "Share Crash" dialogue does not prompt in such cases.

In such case it won't create .ips file in "Analytics Data" under settings.

Hope it is informative to you guys.
Thank you.

Comment: sharing feedback regaring what he faces and learn

Comment: @RamChander Certainly! By acquiring the knowledge provided earlier, I had effectively address issues pertaining to the termination of applications by the operating system.